# html2canvas taking screenshot of DOM element showing blank

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I'm trying to take a screenshot of an element on my page using html2pdf and append it above that element, but it's showing blank.

Here's my script tag:
`<script src='https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js'></script>`

Here's my html (sorry it's a little messy, the important part is that the section has the id "sigSection"):

```
<section id="sigSection">
  <div class="ReactCollapse--collapse" style="height: auto; overflow: initial;">
    <div class="ReactCollapse--content">
      <div style="max-width: 500px;">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 0.5rem;">
          <h3><i class="i-check-circle"></i><span style="margin-left: 0.5rem;">Estimate Accepted</span></h3></div>
        <div id="signature" class="signed-line"><span>JMan</span><span>Apr 27, 2020</span></div>
        <div><span>JMan</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here's my JS:

```
previewImage = () => {
    var element = document.getElementById("sigSection");
    html2canvas(element).then(canvas => {
    element.before(canvas)
    });
};
```

If I change the `element` variable to be `document.body` it works fine, but if I target any specific element the screenshot is blank. Any ideas why this isn't working? Am I just an idiot and missed something obvious?

Any other articles I've seen about this have to do with images not rendering in the screenshot, but I don't have any images in my html.

EDIT: I've got a jsfiddle working that I put in the comments, but I don't know why it works. Would appreciate feedback.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine, it's working here: https://jsfiddle.net/3y648eud/
The issue must be with something else.

Comment: You're right, that does work... but if I add a piece of the rest of my code in, it doesn't anymore. Maybe you can spot the problem? [jsfiddle.net/nwqrv7Ly/3](http://jsfiddle.net/nwqrv7Ly/3)

Comment: You never run `previewImage();` in your JavaScript, you just declare the function. Spot the difference in my jsfiddle? ;)

Comment: I'm running it on click in the input button

Comment: I finally got one that works: [jsfiddle.net/e76r8xy3](https://jsfiddle.net/e76r8xy3). It seems the header was pushing down the canvas, cutting it off (in the not-working fiddle, if I made the header smaller the top of the canvas started showing up). If I move the button to the top of the page and add a separate div to put the canvas, it works. I don't really understand why though, anyone know?

Comment: Whoops, turns out I was the one missing a detail here.
The issue is reported on [Github](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1992) but without a real solution it seems.